# Is there a way to determine if the task was reassigned?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I have the multi-instance parallel workflow.

By using the [`Activiti ScriptTaskListener`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/tasklistener/ScriptTaskListener.html) I write to the some aspect of the `workflow-model.xml` some details of the business process. For example, in the event `start` I write all assignees:

```
...
var assigneesNodeRefs = '';
for(var i = 0; i < bpm_assignees.size(); i++) {
    var assignee = bpm_assignees.get(i);
    assigneesNodeRefs += ' separator ' + assignee.nodeRef;
}
execution.setVariable('mswf_participants', assigneesNodeRefs);
...
```

In the event `complete` I write some another details:

```
...
var reviewDate = new Date();
var bpmComment = task.getVariable('bpm_comment');
var result;
if(task.getVariableLocal('mswf_reviewOutcome') == 'Approve') {
    result = 'Approve';
}
...
```

Etc.

Then, by using the [Alfresco Content Services REST API (tasks)](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/tasks) I can get the [list of variables](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/tasks/listTaskVariables) for my task in JSON format. Next, by using JavaScript, I can parse it and display various data tables in different places.

I'm interested in the ability to reassign assignees.

Let's say, if `assignee_1` reassigns his task to `assignee_2`, I want to write this fact In the `Activiti ScriptTaskListener`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using assignment event

example:

```
<userTask id="test" name="Assignb" activiti:assignee="userName" activiti:formKey="<<formKey>>">
     <extensionElements>

      <activiti:taskListener event="assignment" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
    <activiti:field name="script">
     <activiti:string><![CDATA[

       var currAssignee = task.assignee;
          //gives current task assignee
       logger.log(currAssignee );
     ]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
   </activiti:taskListener>
      <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">

       <activiti:field name="script">
     <activiti:string><![CDATA[

      var currAssignee = task.assignee;

                  ]]></activiti:string>
               </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
         </extensionElements>
 </userTask>
```